# assert failed in Install Ubuntu Touch for tablet Nexus 7(32G)

Tags: ubuntu-touch

As an end user to test ubunbu touch on Nexus 7(32G GSM/HSPA+), encountered a big problem which is error "status 7" or "assert failed"  when manual installing raring-preinstalled-armel+grouper.zip.

pls kindly check the oboved zip file is appropriate for tablet Nexus 7(32G GSM/HSPA+).

Comment: Where did you download this zip file from? Perhaps you should file a bug against this.

Comment: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch-preview/daily-preinstalled/current/

Comment: I have attempted to install saucy and raring and end up with the same exact issue. I am getting an assert failed error when trying to install the .zip.

Answer (score 0):

By manually installing I assume you used recoverymode? That is the correct file for your device. I recommend you check the md5 sum or try re-downloading it. the image would not be in the current directory if it would not install because it would not have passed automated testing.

Comment: I did the same thing he did, and I checked the md5sums and there is absolutely no issues with the files themselves.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are encountering this issue is because you need to run the zip file from  **Ubuntu's recovery image**. The reason you are encountering an assert failed is because the recovery software (i.e. Clockworkmod) you are using doesn't recognize 'getprop' as a valid function. You'll need to find the correct `recovery` image file that corresponds with the zip file you're trying to install.